# Changing text on click

Tags: jquery

How could I go about changing the word 'expand' to 'collapse' with multiple headings with a click function?

```
<h2 class="expand" id="content-1" style="cursor:pointer;" value="One">Click to expand One</h2>
<h2 class="expand" id="content-2" style="cursor:pointer;" value="Two">Click to expand Two</h2>
```

Just not sure how to go about it.

```
 $('.expand').on('click', function() {
     $('#').show();
      $(this).children().text('Click here to collapse ' + value);
    }, function () {
      $('#').hide();
      $(this).children().text('Click here to expand ' + value);
    });
});​
```

Comment: wwy `$('#').show();` ? what u want here .

Comment: well I would assume just '#content-1' if working with only 1 heading however it would need to accept multiple headings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   $('.expand').on('click', function() {
      if($(this).text().indexOf('expand') >0 )
          $(this).text('Click to collapse ' + $(this).attr("value"));
       else
           $(this).text('Click to expand ' + $(this).attr("value"));

    });
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/XY4Xm/

Answer (score 1):

A good way is to check the visibility of whatever element you expand:

```
$('.expand').on('click', function() {
    $("#").toggle();
    $("#").is(":visible") ? $(this).text("Click to collapse") : $(this).text("Click to expand");
});
```

Comment: @Pavlo -- From OP's sample code, I assume `$("#")` is actually the selector of the element that is being shown

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, it would need to accept multiple id's. # was just a place holder since I didn't know how to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.expand').on('click', function() {
   $(this).attr('class','collapse');
    alert(this.className);
});
```

This is just the part to change the class name, you can add your other code in the method as well if neeeded.

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/8VPVg/)